# How to use VGG19 transfer learning pretraining

Tags: model, pytorch, transfer-learning, vgg-net, pre-trained-model

I'm working on a VQA model, and I need some help as I'm new to this.

I want to use transfer learning from the VGG19 network before running the train, so when I start the train, I will have the image features ahead (trying to solve performance issue).

Does it possible to do so? If so, can someone please share an example with pytorch?

below is the relevant code:

```
class img_CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, img_size):

        super(img_CNN, self).__init__()
        self.model = models.vgg19(pretrained=True)
        self.in_features = self.model.classifier[-1].in_features
        self.model.classifier = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.classifier.children())[:-1]) # remove vgg19 last layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features, img_size)

  def forward(self, image):
    #with torch.no_grad():
    img_feature = self.model(image) # (batch, channel, height, width)
    img_feature = self.fc(img_feature)   
    return img_feature

class vqamodel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, output_dim,input_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout, answer_len, que_size, img_size,model_vgg,in_features):
    super(vqamodel,self).__init__()
    self.image=img_CNN(img_size)
    self.question=question_lstm(input_dim, emb_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout,output_dim,que_size)
    self.tanh=nn.Tanh()
    self.relu=nn.ReLU()
    self.dropout=nn.Dropout(dropout)
    self.fc1=nn.Linear(que_size,answer_len) #the input to the linear network is equal to the combain vector
    self.softmax=nn.Softmax(dim=1)


  def forward(self, image, question):
    image_emb=self.image(image)
    question_emb=self.question(question) 
    combine =question_emb*image_emb
    out_feature=self.fc1(combine)
    out_feature=self.relu(out_feature)
      
    return (out_feature)
```

How can I take out the models.vgg19(pretrained=True),run it before the train on the image dataloader and save the image representation in NumPy array?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a pretrained VGG model to extract embedding vectors from images. Here is a possible implementation, using [`torchvision.models.vgg*`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html).

1. First retrieve the pretrained model

   ```
   model = torchvision.models.vgg19(pretrained=True)
   ```

   Its classifier is:

   ```
   >>> model.classifier
   (classifier): Sequential(
       (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
       (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
       (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
       (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
       (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
       (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
       (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
   )
   ```
2. Depending on your finetuning strategy, you can either truncate it to keep some of the  trained dense layers:

   ```
   model.classifier = nn.Sequential(*[model.classifier[i] for i in range(4)])
   ```

   Or replace it altogether with a different set of dense layers wrapped in a `nn.Sequential`:

   ```
   model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
       nn.Linear(25088, 4096),
       nn.ReLU(True),
       nn.Dropout(0.5),
       nn.Linear(4096, 2048))
   ```
3. Additionally, you can freeze the entire head of the model (the feature extractor):

   ```
   for param in model.features.parameters():
       param.requires_grad = False
   ```
4. Then you will be able to use that model to extract image embeddings and perform back propagation to finetune your classifier:

   ```
   >>> model(img) # shape (batchs_size, 2048)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. what if I'll run the model classifier while training with the entire VQA? is it possible?  what command above is actually giving the images as features? model(img)? I planned to perform the backpropagation with the VQA model... is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, as I said you can choose to update the classifier or not depending on your needs. `model(img)` will output the embedding, backpropagation will work naturally since your model will depend on VGG's output.

Comment: if I run it with no change, I get the (batch_size, 1000), the last layer. with your classifier example above, you actually changed the last layer?

Comment: Yes you might want to change the last segment (namely the classifier) of your pretrained model. By default the last layer corresponds to the logit ouput, which has 1000 classes.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I understand better now :)